# Variable.get() not working in KubernetesPodOperator?

Tags: airflow, kubernetespodoperator

I have a task defined using KubernetesPodOperator and I am passing value of the templated variable *run_id* as an environment variable.

What baffles me is that when I use the Jinja template syntax, it works. However when I use the Variable.get() syntax, I got a key error from Airflow.

Here is the code:

```
# this code works!

with DAG(
    dag_id="test",
    default_args={'owner': 'xxx'},
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:
    task_dry_run = KubernetesPodOperator(
        name="test-dry-run",
        image="debian",
        cmds=["bash", "-cx"],
        arguments=["echo", "10"],
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        task_id="dry_run_demo",
        do_xcom_push=True,
        in_cluster=False,
        get_logs=True,
        env_vars={'run_id': "{{ run_id }}"}
    )
```

```
# this code does NOT work!

with DAG(
    dag_id="test",
    default_args={'owner': 'xxx'},
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:
    task_dry_run = KubernetesPodOperator(
        name="test-dry-run",
        image="debian",
        cmds=["bash", "-cx"],
        arguments=["echo", "10"],
        labels={"foo": "bar"},
        task_id="dry_run_demo",
        do_xcom_push=True,
        in_cluster=False,
        get_logs=True,
        env_vars={'run_id': Variable.get("run_id")}
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the "run_id" Airflow Variable doesn't exist and that's why you are seeing issues. The `Variable.get()` call will be executed each time the Scheduler parses the DAG aka parse time (by default every 30 seconds) since it's considered top-level code. Meanwhile, Jinja expressions are not evaluated until runtime. Check out [this documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#airflow-variables) for more info.

You can access Airflow Variables in [Jinja templates](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#variables) as well using `{{ var.value.run_id }}`.

Finally, you can also set a default value in a `Variable.get()` call too like `Variable.get("run_id", default="1234")`.